# SiteMap.CurrentNode return null when using dynamic sitemap

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap

I want to build dynamic sitemap, with highlight parent menu, code behind include 2 methods: Page_Load and smSource_OnMenuItemDataBound like that:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                Sessions.SiteMap = Data.GetSiteMapFile();
                var xmlSmProvider = new XmlSiteMapProvider();
                var providerAttributes = new NameValueCollection();
                providerAttributes.Add("siteMapFile", Sessions.SiteMap);
                xmlSmProvider.Initialize("RoleDemo", providerAttributes);
                xmlSmProvider.BuildSiteMap();
                smSource.Provider = xmlSmProvider;

                horMenu.DataSource = smSource;
                horMenu.DataBind();    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Data.WriteLog(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void smSource_OnMenuItemDataBound(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (SiteMap.CurrentNode != null)
            {
                if (e.Item.Text == SiteMap.CurrentNode.Title)
                {
                    if (e.Item.Parent != null)
                    {
                        e.Item.Parent.Selected = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.Item.Selected = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Data.WriteLog(ex);
        }

    }
```

And my aspx code file like that:

```html
<asp:SiteMapDataSource runat="server" ID="smSource" ShowStartingNode="False"/>
    <asp:Menu runat="server" ID="horMenu" Orientation="Horizontal" OnMenuItemDataBound="smSource_OnMenuItemDataBound">
        <LevelMenuItemStyles>
        <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="main_menu" />
        <asp:MenuItemStyle CssClass="level_menu" />
    </LevelMenuItemStyles>
    </asp:Menu>
```

The problem is **SiteMap.CurrentNode** always return NULL, so that the highlight menu don't working.